# Extracting values from a CSV with looping in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through rows and columns in a CSV (as below)

```
DateTime    762972  763753  763776  769472  793144  799864  812926

01/01/2017 00:00    -1  0.015   -1  0.33    0   0   0.27

01/01/2017 00:15    -1  0.015   -1  0.12    0   0.015   0.06

01/01/2017 00:30    -1  0.015   -1  0.15    0   0   0

01/01/2017 00:45    -1  0.015   -1  0.165   0   0   0.15

01/01/2017 01:00    -1  0.015   -1  0   0   0   0

01/01/2017 01:15    -1  0.015   -1  0   0   0   0.135
```

to generate an output like this

```
762972,  01/01/2017  00:00:00, -1

762972,  01/01/2017  00:15:00, -1

762972,  01/01/2017  00:30:00, -1

...

762753,  01/01/2017  00:00:00, 0.015

762753,  01/01/2017  00:15:00, 0.015

762753,  01/01/2017  00:30:00, 0.015

...

769472, 01/01/2017  00:00:00, 0.33

769472,  01/01/2017  00:15:00, 0.12

769472,  01/01/2017  00:30:00, 0.15
```

So returning the reading for each timestamp, sensor_id, intersect

I am interested in understanding how to do this with Python looping/iteration

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and chunksize:

```
import pandas as pd

for df in pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=1):
    print(df)
```

Also, if the file is not that huge, consider loading full csv into pandas DataFrame and the iterating after that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row)
```